# Why do I have to suppress errors for my function to work

Tags: php, runtime-error, error-suppression

Hi I have a script to log people into my site and within the script is this method (I have changed the values)

```
$con=mysql_connect("mydbdomain", "mydbusername", "mypassword");
```

Now I downloaded a open source file upload program and uploaded it to my server and only allow users who are in the database to use it. It all works great. I however then go and edit the php code which handles the file uploads so that every time a user uploads a file it goes into a directory that matches their username.

```
<?php
/*
* jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Class 7.1.4
* https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
*
* Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
* https://blueimp.net
*
* Licensed under the MIT license:
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
*
* Modified by leathan AxE
*/

class UploadHandler
{
...
...
...
...
    function foo() { ... }
}
?>
```

The function above named foo is where i connect to the db and extract the value of the future directory. But whenever i have this line.

```
$con=mysql_connect("mydbdomain", "mydbusername", "mypassword");
```

instead of

```
$con=@mysql_connect("mydbdomain", "mydbusername", "mypassword");
```

nothing works. why is it when i use @ and suppress errors it all works? Why are there errors? The files are uploaded into the usernames directory perfectly only when using @. I just want to understand what is happening. I dont understand how there can be an error because i use the line

```
$con=mysql_connect("mydbdomain", "mydbusername", "mypassword");
```

in other files and it always works.

Comment: Check error log and post what you find there

Comment: This is what makes me extra mad. On my local machine I dont need to use @ because there are no errors. But when uploaded to 1and1 webhosting I need to use @. How can I check the error.log in 1and1 hosting? I dont think they allow me... ?

Comment: phpinfo() gives no value for error_log and ls ~/log gives No such file or directory. and no access to php.ini. also find / -regex 'blabla' gives pure permission denied :/ so no luck searching. I dont think I have access. can I redirect errors to a file of my choosing within a script to find out?

Comment: @ means you don't need any types of error messages - 
don't use mysql_connect because it is depreciated function
 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742824/mysql-connect-and-mysql-connect

Comment: Yes I was aware. :) Tnx tho.. The code is from 9 years ago :) adding @ is fine for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_connect` is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Probably your provider have `E_DEPRECATED` error level and you get warning whenever you use `mysql_connect`.

Try using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I was aware it was depreciated but am far to lazy! I just wanted to understand what was happening I have now learned about E_DEPRECATED!

That is EXACTLY the what was happening!!!!! THANK YOU!!!